# How to change field defined as REQUIRED to NON_REQUIRED in ArcGIS Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, esri-geodatabase, fields-attributes

I have created some feature classes in a geodatabase and also some fields using this sample code:

```
arcpy.AddField_management("schools", "ref_ID", "LONG", 9, "", "", "refcode", "NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
```

Since the fields where created with field_is_required's parameter as "REQUIRED", how to change it to "NON_REQUIRED" without re-create it?

Comment: How is a field NULLABLE and REQUIRED? Have a read of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n00000100000000 which doesn't list required/nonreqired. I'm not aware of any way to change the required status apart from recreating the database without the required set and using the simple data loader to copy features... alternately export to XML workspace (include data) and change the value there then re-import the XML to a new database.

Comment: It seems that field REQUIRED means that the users can't delete it. It doesn't mean that the value is / isn't required (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000)

Comment: You're right, I don't generally use that property and took it to mean 'population required' - but I guess that's what non-nullable means. I've had success with the export-XML-import workflow; it changes the database to a textural format which can be manipulated allowing for changes that can't usually be made in a database (like, field name) and if you break it it's only a copy, just create a new one.

Comment: The link by PolyGeo says required means *The required state: True if the field must contain a value.*... so which one is correct?? Has to contain a value or field can't be deleted? Last time I really looked at it (ArcGis 8.3) it meant *must contain a value*

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I need to change a lot of fields that are in many databases, so import/export xml wouldn't be a good solution. I could do this using SQLServer's sp_rename, but I can't believe that didn't exist a way to change this property via arcpy...

Comment: Is this a personal or enterprise RDBMS back-end?

Comment: @Jakub It's an enterprise SQLServer RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but the [Field (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004n000000) documentation says that the `required` property is Read and Write so I think that will be the place to start experimenting.

There is a code sample there that could be used as a starting point.  I would try using:

> field.required = False

and see if it sticks.

This sentence:

> Updating a field property only updates the field object, no changes
>   are made to the actual field in the table or feature class.

suggests to me that it may be able to "unlock" the field to ArcPy so that it can be deleted so that a new field can added with the desired setting.

Comment: It seems to work. I will test it.

Comment: It didn't work. I tryied this code without success:

Comment: fields = arcpy.ListFields(FeatureClass)
  for field in fields:
    # Print field properties
    print("Field:       {0}".format(field.name))
    print("Alias:       {0}".format(field.aliasName))
    print("Type:        {0}".format(field.type))
    print("Is Editable: {0}".format(field.editable))
    print("Required:    {0}".format(field.required))
    print("Scale:       {0}".format(field.scale))
    print("Precision:   {0}".format(field.precision))
      
    if field.name == "CdLote_A":
      field.required = False
      field.name = "CdLote"
      print "OK"
      break

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide what type of database you were using I could provide a better answer but you could change the column settings to allow null. If your data is versioned I would recommend unversioning that layer which will require you to do a post/reconcile and compress or at least a compress. This way you can just go into the backend and change the property to for allow nulls to true if you were using SQL server you could do this in sql server management studio. Honestly though recreating is probably the easiest way.

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2012 Geodatabase. My problem is not related with null / not null. I was trying to rename some field without success. My data is not versioned. Since I am the data owner, I think that I can't rename it because of the REQUIRED parameter I have used when the field was created... for example:  arcpy.AddField_management(Tabela 
,"Codigo","SHORT","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","REQUIRED","#")

Comment: I was mistaken I was thinking required value within the column.